# Propagating errors to cause HUnit tests to fail

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, hunit

I am writing an HUnit test for a function `eval :: Wff -> Assignment -> Maybe Bool`. `Wff` is a custom data type which is an abstract parse tree for a simplified subset of boolean expressions:

```
data Wff = Var Name
         | Not Wff
         | Or Wff Wff
         deriving (Eq)
```

and `Assignment` is a type alias for an associative list which gives a boolean value for each variable in a `Wff`:

```
type Assignment = [(Name, Bool)]
```

My current test looks like this:

```
testEval :: Test
testEval = "Test eval"
        ~: TestList $ zipWith (\e (Just a) -> e ~=? a) expected (eval wff <$> assignments)
    where expected = [True, False]
          assignments = [[('p', True)], [('p', False)]]
          Right wff = parse wffStr
          wffStr = "p"
```

Both of the tests constructed pass. However, the test is not very robust. If I modify it with a more complicated value for `wffStr` but make a typo, the pattern `Right wff` will fail because `parse` will return a `Left String` instead of a `Rigth Wff`. This causes the test run to abort and I'd rather get a failure for the few bad tests and the actual results for the rest. How can I modify my current structure so that the error propagates to cause the test to fail instead of aborting all together?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about HUnit, but: can you just tell it what to do when the parse fails?

```
testEval = case parse wffStr of
    Left _ -> {- use HUnit's functions to make a failing test case -}
    Right wff -> "Test eval" ~: TestList $ {- ... -}
    where expected = [True, False]
          {- ... -}
```

Comment: This looks like an agreeable solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: p.s. My question is probably more about mixing monads rather than about HUnit. Maybe I need to find a way to rephrase my question to highlight that I am using an `Either String` monad along with a list of `Maybe` monads. I'm sure there is some nice way of dealing with this, but I haven't found it yet.